# Выполнение действий после деплоя WAR приложения в WildFly8

Tags: java-ee, servlet, wildfly, jboss, war

Есть задача - при запуске сервера автоматически запускать viber бота (находится в отдельной war). Чтобы его запустить нужно указать свой url и написать свой сервлет, на который viber будет отправлять запросы. Проблема в том, что при использовании ServletContextListener, в котором я отправляю свой url viber'у, существует вероятность, что war не задеплоится (на момент, когда viber будет отправлять запрос) и viber не достучится до моего сервлета.
Нигде не нашёл можно ли отследить, что war задеплоился и после этого отправлять свой url viber'у? Или может быть есть другие варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Конечно есть!

1. Забить на то, что вибер не достучится.
   Вам конечно лучше знать, что может плохого случиться.
   Но с другой стороны всякие неприятности могут происходить и во время работы.  Кто-нибудь оборвёт провода и вибер опять не сможет достучаться.
2. Точно `ServletContextListener` вызывается во время деплоя, а не после успешного его завершения?
3. Servlet-ы тоже можно инициализировать при запуске. Параметр `loadOnStartup` аннотации `@WebServlet`.
   `@WebServlet(value="path", loadOnStartup = 1)`   В методе init() или конструкторе отправить url виберу.
4. Можно сделать ejb-бин с аннотациями `@Startup` и методом `@PostConstruct`.  Уже не знаю есть ли вероятность того, что такой бин будет создан, а потом war вдруг не задеплоится. Но url скорее всего будет трудно вычислить. Не помню есть ли способ в ejb узнать contextPath.

Далее не способ выполнения действий после деплоя, а способ подключения внешних информ. систем.

Так вот, для связи в внешними системами (EIS) в javaee предусмотрели `Java EE Connector Architecture` или `JCA`.
Сложнова-то конечно. Зато вибер может достучаться, даже когда приложение не задеплоено.

Comment: Забить не могу, т.к. нужно получать ответы пользователей.
У меня запрос работает синхронно: отправили webhook, потом вайбер сделал запрос на указанный webhook, потом вернул ответ. Т.е. я не смогу отправку webhook использовать в init, т.к. она заканчивается после того как вайбер пробует и не может достучаться до сервлета. У меня всё работало при ассинхронных запросах, но я засомневался, вдруг, и при ассинхронном запросе у меня сервлет не успеет запуститься на момент отправки webhook. ServletContextListener (отлаживал в debug) запускается во время деплоя (файлы .dodeploy и .isdeploying)